# ggplot2 move x-axis to top (intersect with reversed y axis at 0)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a figure which have reversed y-axis and x-axis at y=0.
y axis was reversed with scale_y_reverse, but x-axis stayed at the bottom.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x= conc, y=depth, group=factor(stn), color=factor(stn)))+
geom_point(shape=1)+
geom_path(alpha=0.5)+
scale_y_reverse(limits=(c(20,0)), expand=c(0,0))+   
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

I tried the code from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2-dev/JkJU5CLBkQw) like in below, but didn't work.

```
p + 
scale_x_continuous(guide = guide_axis(position = "top")) + 
scale_y_continuous(guide = guide_axis(position = "right"))
```

I don't need to have two x-axis, simply just move from bottom to the top.

Comment: The [feature request](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/619) for this is still open. I don't think it has been implemented yet. That means you would have to muck around on the grid level.

Comment: If it's a one-off, you could consider saving the plot as a vector/PDF and then moving the axis in vector drawing software (e.g. Inkscape).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I hope they'll implement this soon. Tentatively I started editing on Inkscape.

Comment: Does anyone understand the reasoning behind this feature not being implemented? Is there some philosphy with respect to Grammer of Graphics that shies away from having an x-axis on the top of a plot?

Comment: @Matt O'Brien, there is a reluctance to implement it because it can be mis-used. I don't get it. ``The Economist`` doesn't get it...

Answer (score 4):

This is still not possible in `ggplot2`, but it is possible in `ggvis`, which combines the `ggplot2` grammer with `dplyr` pipelines. Just use the `add_axis` function to put the axis at the top.

```
# sample data
N <- 20
df <- data.frame(conc = seq(0, N), 
                 depth = runif(N+1, 0, 20), 
                 stn = rep(1:4, length=N+1))
# ggplot version
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x= conc, y=depth, group=factor(stn), color=factor(stn)))+
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  geom_path(alpha=0.5)+
  scale_y_reverse(limits=(c(20,0)), expand=c(0,0))+   
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
p
# ggvis version
require(ggvis)
df %>% transform(stn = factor(stn)) %>%
  ggvis(x = ~conc, y = ~depth, stroke = ~stn) %>%
  layer_points(shape := "circle", fill := "white") %>%
  layer_lines(opacity := 0.5) %>%
  scale_numeric("y", reverse=TRUE, domain=c(0,20), expand=c(0,0)) %>%
  scale_numeric("x", expand=c(0,0)) %>%
  add_axis("x", orient = "top")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
library(cowplot)
ggdraw(switch_axis_position(p, axis = 'x'))
```

Comment: Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50589549/5060792